# Swing GUI with FlowLayout, won't display on JFrame more than last component added

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, flowlayout

I am trying to display 2 panels that I have created in separate files one at the top and one at the bottom of my GUI with a button group between them. However, the window is only displaying one panel or the button group at a time. The panels and button group are displaying properly but only the last one added to the frame is being displayed at any given execution.

Here is the current code without any layouts...

```
package UserGUI;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class RealFrame extends JFrame {
JButton Close = new JButton("Close");
JButton Proceed = new JButton("Proceed");
AuthorPanel header = new AuthorPanel();
FreeSpacePanel disk = new FreeSpacePanel();

public RealFrame() {
    super();       
    ButtonGroup Ops = new ButtonGroup();
    Ops.add(Close);
    Ops.add(Proceed);
    JPanel OPS = new JPanel();
    OPS.add(Close);
    OPS.add(Proceed);
    add(disk);
    add(OPS);
    add(header);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500,500);
    setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: `"Swing GUI with FlowLayout"` -- Where the heck do you set any container's layout manager to FlowLayout? You may be assuming a bit too much here.

Comment: 1) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is a `CONSTANT_ALL_UPPER`) and use it consistently. 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Thank you all, very much! That was indeed my issue, i have changed the layout settings, and it works now. Thank you @AndrewThompson I have been teaching myself from samples and a lot of trial-and-error so I will go back through and correct my poor nomenclature. HovercraftFullOfEels, I posted that as the title because before posting my code I had used FlowLayout on all of the components, but I removed it to give blank code. I made note of that in the comment(s) preceding the code; sorry for the confusion.

Comment: As you seem to have noticed, exactly one person can be notified from any comment, so @HovercraftFullOfEels needs to be separately notified.  ;)

Comment: Your question is about layouts and yet you post code "without layouts", huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, so when you do...

```
add(disk);
add(OPS);
add(header);
```

You're adding each component to the same location (the `CENTRE` position), but the `BorderLayout` will only layout the last one added.

Instead, you should use something more like...

```
add(disk, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(OPS);
add(header, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

See [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

```
add(disk);
add(OPS);
add(header);
```

The default layout manager of the content pane of the `JFrame` is a `BorderLayout`. If you don't specify a constraint then the component is added to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`. Only one component can be added to the CENTER so the only the last component is displayed.

Try:

```
add(disk, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(OPS, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(header, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

to see the difference.

Or try another layout manager on the frame. See [How to Use Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information.